# One-Particle Self-Energy (Yang-Mills)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, gauge-theory, yang-mills, self-energy

I've been asking about an interesting question when i was calculating the self energy of a Gauge boson in Yang-Mills theory.

I think that the correct way to think this problem is: the incident particle with $q$ momenta, self-interacting in some way, and producing a particle with $q'$ momenta.

[image]

But in majority of textbooks, they simply ignore the fact that the outgoing particle has the momenta equal $q'$, not necessary equal the incident momenta, and we need to carry the $\delta(q-q')$ final factor in the scattering amplitude.

Am i thinking correctly?
We really need to carry the delta factor?
And if the outgoing momento really is equal the incident momenta, e need to carry the factor $\delta(0)$?

Comment: The full amplitude has the form ${\cal A} = {\cal M}(q,q') (2\pi)^4 \delta^4 ( q - q' )$. Of course the $\delta$-function is present in ${\cal A}$, but it is extracted out in order to define ${\cal M}(q,q')$ the thing that is calculated in the above Feynman diagram. However, since we know that the momentum conserving $\delta$-function is present, we can set $q' = q$ in ${\cal M}$ and simply compute the diagram with equal momenta.